# Can't get the filtered items from my filtered list inside a modal

Tags: angularjs, filter, pagination, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a page where I can open a modal window when selecting a certain "instruction"
When that modal window is loaded, I have inside of it a text input for searching, an ordered list to list all of the "instructions" (except the one I selected), a dropdown list to select the amount of instructions I want to see per page, 2 buttons for next and previous page as well as text showing the current page and how many page there is.

This is what it looks like (the Manual dropdown list does nothing for now)
[image: Looks like this]

So far, I get all my instructions just right, my filter work, the result per page works, the next and previous button change the page... but it seems like my numberOfPages function isn't working.

This is the modal HTML page:

```
<div>
        Search: <input type="text" ng-model="search.Description"/> Manual: 
        <select ng-options="manual.Description for manual in manuals">

        </select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="table clearfix" style="max-width: 800px; max-height: 300px; overflow: scroll;">
        <ol class="table-body clearfix">
            <li class="table-row clearfix" ng-repeat="item in ( filteredItems = ( instructions | filter:search:strict)) | startFrom:currentPage*showLimit | limitTo:showLimit" ng-include="'js/manuals/manuals-item-instruction-attachment-showInstruction.html'"></li>
        </ol>

    </div>
    <div>
        <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">Previous</button>
            Page: {{currentPage + 1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
        <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= numberOfPages() - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage + 1">Next</button>
        Results per page:
        <select ng-model="showLimit">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

This is the function where my modal is created and opened

```
openreference: function (item) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'js/manuals/manuals-item-instruction-attachment.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            instruction: function () {
                return item;
            }
        }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    },
    function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
}
```

And this is my modal controller

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, instruction) {
    $scope.showLimit = 10;
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.numberOfPages = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage + 1 > Math.ceil($scope.filteredItems.length / $scope.showLimit)) {
            $scope.currentPage = 0;
        }
        return Math.ceil($scope.filteredItems.length / $scope.showLimit);
    }
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '../api/Instructions/GetAllOtherInstructions', params: { 'instructionId': instruction.Id} }).success(function (result) {
        $scope.instructions = result;
    });
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

After debugging, my filteredItems in the numberOfPages function was always undefined no matter where I tried to place the numberOfPages function in my code.

Why are my filteredItems from the ng-repeat always undefined? I have the same thing in a non-modal page and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: Where's the code that's supposed to set `filteredItems`?  In the `ng-repeat` html?  I don't think that's valid.

Comment: It is valid, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/7WY_BmFzd3U). I also have it in a page where I list all the users and filter them with a pagination. It's the exact same thing as I have here except it's not in a modal. I have a feeling I only made a dumb mistake but I can't put my finger on what I do wrong.

Comment: Can you use batarang to debug your scopes?  Does the modal have its own scope that filteredItems isn't getting to?

Comment: I'm not sure how Batarang work, I'll read on it. At first glance, I can see that in the scope where I have all the things that work (currentPage, the selected instruction, etc.) and that in the next branch of scope, I have filteredItems with all my filtered instructions

Comment: @Jason Goemaat After setting a watch on my $scope, I found the filteredItems as a child scope like in the batarang debug. Is there anyways to have filteredItems in it's parent scope or should I change the $scope.filteredItems in my numberOfPages function to reference on the $scope child filteredItems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reply to the comment, try creating an object to hold the filteredItems property.  That will inherit and the property will be created on the parent object:

```
$scope.data = { };
```

html:

```
<li class="table-row clearfix" 
    ng-repeat="item in ( data.filteredItems = ( instructions | filter:search:strict)) | startFrom:currentPage*showLimit | limitTo:showLimit" 
    ng-include="'js/manuals/manuals-item-instruction-attachment-showInstruction.html'"></li>
```