# Retreiving filteredItems from uib-typeahead custom popup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

### Retreiving filteredItems from ng-repeat in controller through $scope doesn't work

I am trying to get filtered items from ng-repeat but I get undefined when console logging the value of `$scope.filteredItems`. I even tried the solution provided in [Can't get the filtered items from my filtered list inside a modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467574/cant-get-the-filtered-items-from-my-filtered-list-inside-a-modal?rq=1) but it didn't work either.

The `ng-repeat` is in a [uib-typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!typeahead) custom popup templates for typeahead's dropdown. I am trying to get the filtered value in the parent controller.

**example-input.component.ts**

```
/////////////////////////////////
componentController.$inject = ['$scope', 'exampleDataService'];
function componentController($scope, exampleDataService) {

    var someInput = this;
    someInput.typedText = '';
    someInput.onKeyPress = onKeyPress;
    return;

    /////////////////////////////////
    //controller implementation detail
    /////////////////////////////////

    function onKeyPress(){
        console.log($scope.filteredItems); // prints undefined
    }
}
```

#### UIB-Typeahead Custom Template for Popup

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="input-custom-template.html">
    <ul class='dropdown-menu' ng-show='isOpen() && !moveInProgress'
        ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}"
        role='listbox' aria-hidden='{{!isOpen()}}' match-limit  in-view-container> 
        <li style="max-height:0;overflow:hidden"><span in-view="$inview && matchLimit.reset()"> </span></li>
        <li ng-repeat='match in (filteredItems = (matches | someMatchSort:query | limitTo:matchLimit.value)) track by some.model.example '
            ng-class='{active: isActive($index) }'
            ng-mouseenter='selectActive($index)'
            ng-click='selectMatch($index, $event)'
            role='option' id='{{::match.id}}'
            in-view="!$inview && isActive($index) && scrollTarget.scrollIntoView()" 
            scroll-target
            >
            <div uib-typeahead-match index='$index' match='match'
                 query='query' template-url='templateUrl'>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="someInput.typedText" typeahead-min-length="1"
       uib-typeahead="option.example as option.value for option in someInput.options | filter:{value:$viewValue}"
       class="form-control input-text-example icon-search"
       placeholder="example"
       typeahead-popup-template-url="input-custom-template.html"
       ng-keypress="someInput.onKeyPress()"/>
```

If you need any additional info pls let me know. There is also a filter called **someMatchSort.filter.ts** but I'm not sure if it makes difference to add it here. Anyways let me know, I will update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `ng-keyup` in your case. 
Then in your component write like so

```
function onKeyPress(){
     console.log($scope.$$childHead.matches.length);
}
```